# MySQL Select grouping with a specific criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a sql table that looks like this:

```
gameId   team1   team2   date   stage
1          5       2     xx/xx    0
2          3       4     xx/xx    0
3          7       1     xx/xx    0
5          5       3     xx/xx    8
6          7       2     xx/xx    8
7          5       3     xx/xx    5
8          7       2     xx/xx    5
```

I want to SELECT ALL and order group it by stage in a specific order (8, 0, 5) and within each group have it ordered by date.

I thought of doing:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC GROUP BY stage
```

But I am not sure how to give a criteria for the grouping because it does not follow a numeric logic.

The goal is to show the items by stage in the specific order I mentioned.

Comment: show your expected output ?

Comment: If there are not much stage-items, you could think about an ENUM(). Otherwise I would use a joined stage-table which uses an ordering. If this is possible?

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD(stage, 8,0,5) DESC` ? _P.S._ Your `GROUP BY` clause is a bit _short_ for your `SELECT` (however MySQL is very liberal to such things, so I guess you don't receive any errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
ORDER BY
        FIND_IN_SET(stage, '8,0,5'),
        date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(stage, '8', '0', '5'), date DESC GROUP BY stage;
```